# If $1\in\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ while $A_i=\{\sum_{j=1}^i\frac{9}{10^j}\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hi I found the general definition of union of sets in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)).

So I would like to ask if $1\in\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ while $A_i=\{\sum_{j=1}^i\frac{9}{10^j}\}$

From the definition, there must exists a set that make $1\in A_i$ so that $1\in\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ sustains.

And for set it does not have the definition of distance. So does it simply implies that $1\not\in\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ or there would be a definition of $i=\infty$ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ is a notation for $\bigcup\limits_{i\in\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}}A_i$, i.e. for the set $X$ such that, for all $x$, $x\in X$ if and only if there is some natural number $i\ge1$ such that $x\in A_i$.

Therefore your $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ does not contain $1$.